# Animated gif in android

Tags: android

i want to use animated gif in android. hows this possible? is it compatible in 1.6,2.0?

Answer (score 3):

Animated gif support is not available in 1.6 SDK though it is available in 2.2(Froyo)

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3422

Answer (score 0):

you can decompose the animated gif into frames (separate gif files) and animate them using an animationdrawable in an imageview.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

yes, it is compatible with 1.6.